# Django Rest Framework: serializer response error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a problem with my viewset in DRF:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """
    :return: filtered queryset based on request query_param

    """
    # todo#amedeo: improve the readability code
    qs = super(ChecklistViewSet, self).get_queryset()
    _pk = self.kwargs['pk']

    if self.request.method == 'PUT':
        instance = qs.filter(pk=int(_pk)).first()
        # pass in the instance we want to update
        serializer = ChecklistSerializer(instance, self.request.data)

        # validate and update
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            serializer_dict = serializer.data
            serializer_dict["message"] = "Checklist updated successfully."
            return response.Response(serializer_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in my code the objetc was saved, but the response give an error that say:

> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'model'

My serializer is:

```
class ChecklistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Checklist
    fields = ('id', 'approved_by', 'role', 'hardship_classification',
              'total_capacity', 'capacity_for_residents', 'checklist_type',
              'state', 'pdf', 'submitting_afp', 'disabled', 'location')
```

i call by client PUT method passing json:

```
{
"approved_by": "Test",
"role": "test_role_4",
"hardship_classification": "test_6",
"total_capacity": "50",
"capacity_for_residents": "350",
"checklist_type": "permanent",
"state": "qcl_draft",
"pdf": null,
"submitting_afp": 3999,
"disabled": false,
"location": 97
}
```

but i receved that Error. The model was saved but Response give me the Error

> Internal Server Error: /api/v1/checklists/3/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
>       self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 401, in initial
>       self.check_permissions(request)
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 334, in check_permissions
>       if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
>     File "/home/adifilippo/.envs/accomodation/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 206, in has_permission
>       perms = self.get_required_permissions(request.method, queryset.model)
>   AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'model'
>   "PUT /api/v1/checklists/3/ HTTP/1.1" 500 42934

enter code here

Comment: can you post `class ChecklistSerializer`

Comment: class ChecklistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Checklist
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'approved_by', 'role', 'hardship_classification',
                  'total_capacity', 'capacity_for_residents', 'checklist_type',
                  'state', 'pdf', 'submitting_afp', 'disabled', 'location')

Comment: @AmedeoDiFilippo can you post the full traceback

Comment: @WillKeeling   perms = self.get_required_permissions(request.method, queryset.model)
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'model'
"PUT /api/v1/checklists/3/ HTTP/1.1" 500 42934

Answer (score 2):

the `get_queryset` method should return the `queryset` not `Response` and the update action should be overrided in the `put` method. Read here [class-based-views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) and 
[filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) for more details. May be you need to remove the `get_queryset` overriding and just add the `put` method somethig like this:

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    instance = self.get_object(pk)
    # pass in the instance we want to update
    serializer = ChecklistSerializer(instance, self.request.data)

    # validate and update
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        serializer_dict = serializer.data
        serializer_dict["message"] = "Checklist updated successfully."
        return response.Response(serializer_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    else:
        return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: i'm using Django 1.11 on my project

Comment: it doesn't matter django version. why you write it?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in Django and python. For that method i define the correct url in my urls file .*py?  My urls.py is this:                                     router.register(r'checklists', checklist.ChecklistViewSet, base_name='checklists')


urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
from django.shortcuts import get_objects_or_404

class YourAPIView(ModelViewSet):
   def put(self, request, pk):
       instance = get_objects_or_404(YourModel, pk=pk)
       serializer = ChecklistSerializer(instance, self.request.data)

# validate and update
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           serializer_dict = serializer.data
           serializer_dict["message"] = "Checklist updated successfully."
           return response.Response(serializer_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```